# ImportError: cannot import name XGBClassifier

Tags: python-2.7

I have been trying to forecast a time series using the following code:

```
# First XGBoost model for Pima Indians dataset
from numpy import loadtxt
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
# load data
dataset = loadtxt(``'pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=",")
# split data into X and y
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# split data into train and test sets
seed = 7
test_size = 0.33
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y,test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)
# fit model no training data  
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# make predictions for test data
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
# evaluate predictions
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

> And I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DMatrix'
```

How do I correct this error?

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Your X and Y data sets seem to overlap:
Both include column 8 of the input data source.

X = dataset[:,0:8]    Y = dataset[:,8]

Should X =  dataset[:,0:7] instead?